# Desktop installation fails on Dell Precision T1600 with Nvidia Quadro card?

Tags: installation, dell

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop on a Dell Precision T1600, however, I get a blank screen with only a blinking cursor in the top left hand corner (this is after the grey screen with the small Ubuntu logo at the bottom).

If I remove the Nvidia Quadro 2000 card and plug a monitor into the built-in VGA port, then the installation works fine.

Also, I've tried an Nvidia Quadro 2000D by PNY, but I get the same problem.

Has anyone installed Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop on a Dell Precision workstation?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Reading other posts on [older versions of Ubuntu on Dell's precision T1600](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1806957) suggests that it may be an isue with the video card.  This convinced me to try a different connection for my monitor (VGA cord instead of a DVI-D cord).

And it works. I don't fully understand why this is the case, but I am now running ubuntu from the CD and was able to successfully install it using the external VGA port.

Comment: Just installed ubunto 12.04 - 64 bit, so using the VGA port for my monitor fixed the issue.